# C++ insertion/extraction operator

Tags: c++, overloading

I am having a bit of trouble with the extraction operator. It is reading in continuous lines of code.

The function is:

```
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Points2D &some_points) {
        //If sequence exists, deallocate it.
        if(some_points.sequence_ != NULL){
            delete some_points.sequence_;
            some_points.sequence_ = nullptr;
        }

        in >> some_points.size_;

        some_points.sequence_ = new std::array<Object, 2> [some_points.size()];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < some_points.size(); i++){
            in >> some_points.sequence_[i][0] >> some_points.sequence_[i][1];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        return in;

    };
```

It is supposed to add the values, The autograder for this assignment is not working properly because the input is not correct.

```
Your program is being tested for the following input:
4  1.5 2.5 6.6 9.2 4.5 3.2 5.4
3  200.0 6.0 450.2 8.8 9.6 3.4

Your program produced the following output:
Enter a sequence of points (double)

(1.5, 2.5) (6.6, 9.2) (4.5, 3.2) (5.4, 3) //THIS IS WHERE IT IS HAPPENING, ALLOCATES 5.4 AND 3 
                                          //TOGETHER INSTEAD OF STOPPING 
Enter a sequence of points (double)

(0, 6) (450.2, 8.8) (9.6, 3.4) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) 
(0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) ... (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0)
```

This line is stated to have 4 pairs, it should abort the program because 5.4 does not have any other value to assign to it.

```
4  1.5 2.5 6.6 9.2 4.5 3.2 5.4 // (1.5,2.5) (6.6,9.2) (4.5,3.2)
```

This line of 3 pairs is fine as every one of them has a pair

```
3  200.0 6.0 450.2 8.8 9.6 3.4 // (200.0,6.0) (450.2,8.8) (9.6,3.4)
```

**My question is how do I make it so my program aborts if it doesn't have a second value instead of reading it from the next line?**

Comment: You might consider reading a line at a time and using a `stringstream` to parse it with error checking for missing values and such.

Comment: Side note: If you can use `std::array` you should see if `std::vector` reduces the the grunt work of managing your own dynamic `sequence_` buffer without breaking some other requirement.

Comment: The code you have shown allocates `some_points.sequence_ = new std::array<Object, 2> [some_points.size()]` (i.e. a `new []` expression) and releases it using a non-array `delete` expression.    Which means that calling the operator twice in succession (e.g. `some_stream >> some_points; some_stream >> some_points;`) gives undefined behaviour.   If other functions related to `Points2D` do similar things (e.g. constructor allocates using `new[]` and destructor releases using non-array `delete`) the behaviour is also undefined.